# TypeMisMatchException in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Following is my Person class:

```
package com.subir.sample;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name ="person",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames= {"NAME"})})
public class Person implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2728179031744032393L;
int age;
String name;
char isVip;

public Person() {
}
public Person(int age, String name, char isVip) {
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
    this.isVip = isVip;
}
@Id
@Column(name="AGE")
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
@Id
@Column(name="NAME")
//@OneToMany(mappedBy="NAME")
private Set <Subject> subjects;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Id
@Column(name="ISVIP")
public char getIsVip() {
    return isVip;
}
public void setIsVip(char isVip) {
    this.isVip = isVip;
}
}
```

And the following is my class for add and view persons.

```
package com.subir.sample;

import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class PersonDbAccess {
public static void addPerson(String name, int age, char isVip, Session session, org.hibernate.Transaction tx) {
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Person p = new Person(age, name, isVip);
        session.save(p);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public static void viewPerson(String name, Session session) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Name value in view method is :: " + name);
        Person person = (Person)session.get(Person.class, name);
        System.out.println("Person.class is ::" + Person.class + " Person.class.getName is :: "
                + Person.class.getName() + " Person.class.getSimpleName() is :: " + Person.class.getSimpleName()
                + " Person.class.getCanonicalName is :: " + Person.class.getCanonicalName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtils.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    String name = "Subir";
    int age = 20;
    char isVip = 'Y';
    // addPerson(name,age,isVip,session,tx);
    viewPerson("Subir", session);
}
}
```

And following is my stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class com.subir.sample.Person. Expected: class com.subir.sample.Person, got class java.lang.String
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.checkIdClass(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:166)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:86)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1240)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:204)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2842)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2816)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1076)
at com.subir.sample.PersonDbAccess.main(PersonDbAccess.java:53)
```

Even though, I am passing `object.class,String` in the `get` method of the `session` object, it is giving me type mismatch exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the ID to your hibernate session get method. In your case you have a compound key , fetching only by name might result in more than one object being returned which contradicts with the nature of the get operation which returns a single object by primary key.

You need to use a Criteria or Query here.

On another note if you want to use the Session.get method, instead of marking multiple columns with ID which is not JPA complient you should create an EmbededId and use it in the Session.get method. Then it will not incompatible type.

Read https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

UPDATE:
I can see you have Unique constraint on name. Why do you need the AGE and the isVip to be part of your key , because marking them with ID you are effectivly making them part of your key.